# Python function is plotting all histograms into same plot instead of creating different plots for each iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
list1 = ['PG','UN','HH-RF','MKT-RF']
f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True)
for i in (list1):
    sns.distplot(df[i], kde=False, bins=40)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the argument `ax` inside distplot. 
First of all, you do not need a grid `6x6` since you have a list made of 4 elements.
You can modify the code as follow:

```
list1 = ['PG','UN','HH-RF','MKT-RF']
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(20, 20), sharex=True)
ax_list = axes.flatten()
for index, i in enumerate(list1):
    sns.distplot(df[i], kde=False, bins=40, ax=ax_list[index])
    # Showing the x label
    ax_list[index].set_xlabel(i)
```

This way you will plot each `df` into a specific box of the subplots.

Comment: I have tried implementing it but now the labels on the x-axis have been disappeared even though I am seeing different plots.

Comment: I don't think `ax_list[index].xlabel(i)` would work. You need `ax_list[index].set_xlabel(i)`